# Manually update Malwarebytes without Internet access

Tags: windows, safe-mode, malwarebytes

At my work, we use multiple AVs for virus-infested computers. One of the last ones I use is [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), and I still love it. In the past, I've been able to boot into `Safe Mode with Command Prompt` on Windows XP or higher, run the install file from `%PROGRAMDATA%\Malwarebytes\Anti-Malware`, then copy the `rules.def` file into the same folder on the other computer to update it.

Since the new versions with the blue icon, I have not been able to do that, as it is obviously looking elsewhere for other files, or different settings. If I copy the file over the old `rules.def` file, MWB just says that it is corrupt and needs to be reinstalled or get new updates online.

How can I manually update Malwarebytes without Internet access, while in Safe Mode with Command Prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to moving the `rules.ref` file (or `rules.def` as you note possibly?), it looks like versions 1.60 and newer also need to update the `database.conf` file inside the `Configuration` folder, which is in the same folder as `rules.ref`.

Reference [Here](http://www.mytechguide.org/7213/how-to-manually-download-definition-updates-for-malwarebytes-anti-malware/)